# How to write quartile and StDev in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table like this:

**table's name:** pelamarmagisterrangkuman

[image]

then I made sql like this to find **average, min, max value**

```
select `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`major` AS `ProgramStudi`,
count(usia) as N,
AVG(usia) as Mean,
MIN(usia) as Minimum,
MAX(usia) as Maximum
from `pelamarmagisterrangkuman` group by `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`major`
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

now, I want to find quartile and stdev value, but I don't know how to write on sql. Could somebody please help me to solve that problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is MySQL, you should tag it so.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, you've got [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql) and [STDEV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stdev-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Standard deviation is easy:

```
select p.major AS ProgramStudi,
       count(usia) as N, AVG(usia) as Mean,
       MIN(usia) as Minimum, MAX(usia) as Maximum,
       STDDEV(usia)
from `pelamarmagisterrangkuman` p
group by p.major;
```

Quartiles are much harder.  I think the most reliable way might be to use variables:

```
select p.major AS ProgramStudi,
       count(usia) as N, AVG(usia) as Mean,
       MIN(usia) as Minimum, MAX(usia) as Maximum,
       STDDEV(usia) as stddev,
       max(case when floor(0.25*pp.cnt) = rn then usia end) as quartile_1,
       max(case when floor(0.50*pp.cnt) = rn then usia end) as quartile_2,
       max(case when floor(0.75*pp.cnt) = rn then usia end) as quartile_3
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@m = p.major, @rn + 1,
                        if(@m := p.major, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from pelamarmagisterrangkuman p cross join
           (select @m := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by p.major, p.usia
     ) p join
     (select p.major, count(*) as cnt
      from pelamarmagisterrangkuman p
      group by p.major
     ) pp
     on p.major = pp.major
group by p.major;
```

Comment: I tried that query, but the result for all quartiles of that query is NULL :(

Comment: @r34627673 . . . It was using the wrong value for the count for each `major`.  That problem should be fixed.

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: @r34627673 . .  . Don't get what?  The quartiles need the overall count for each major.  This calculates that directly using a subquery.

Comment: but, why can there be zero value in quartile 3? As example, there is value in quartile 1 and 2 but quartile 3 has a zero value

Comment: @r34627673 . . . That will happen when there are very few values for a `major` or lots of duplicate values.

Comment: yeah, Maybe, it is caused by the problem that usia has some zero values. What may I do so that I can count the quartiles where usia is not null?

Comment: when I tried that query, why quartile 1 is greater than quartile 3?